# How does a weak_ptr know that the shared resources has expired?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, weak-ptr, refcounting

Considering the following code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct MySharedStruct
{
  int i;
};

void print_value_of_i(weak_ptr<MySharedStruct> weakPtr)
{
  if (shared_ptr<MySharedStruct> sp = weakPtr.lock())
  { cout << "Value of i = " << sp->i << endl; }
  else
  { cout << "Resource has expired"; }
}

int main()
{
  shared_ptr<MySharedStruct> sharedPtr(new MySharedStruct() );
  sharedPtr->i = 5;

  weak_ptr<MySharedStruct> weakPtr;
  weakPtr = sharedPtr;

  print_value_of_i(weakPtr);

  sharedPtr.reset(new MySharedStruct() ); // <<----- How does weak_ptr know it has expired after this line executes?
  sharedPtr->i = 10;

  print_value_of_i(weakPtr);

  return 0;
}
```

How does the `weak_ptr` know it has expired considering the resource that `shared_ptr` was referencing has been essentially replaced by another resource? What does `weak_ptr` keep track of to know for sure that the *old* shared resource was destroyed and replaced by the *new* shared resource?  Example definitions (if relevant) of methods such `lock` in `weak_ptr` would be appreciated.

Comment: Regarding an example implementation, http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/boost/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.hpp

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The control block allocated when a `shared_ptr` is created from a plain pointer contains both the reference counter for the object and the pointer to the object itself and the custom deleter object if any. When that reference counter reaches zero the object is released and the pointer is set to null. So, when the object reference counter is zero it means that the object is gone.

For x86 and x86-64 they use atomic operations and no explicit locking (no mutex or spinlock). The trick of the implementation is a special lock-free (code language for busy spin) function `atomic_conditional_increment` that only increments the object reference counter if it is not zero. It is used in the implementation of `weak_ptr::lock` function to cope with a race when more than one thread tries to create a `shared_ptr` from the same `weak_ptr` with object reference counter being zero. See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_gcc_x86.hpp

The control block itself is shared between `shared_ptr`'s and `weak_ptr`'s and has another reference counter for itself, so that it stays alive till the last reference to it is released.

When a `shared_ptr` is reassigned it points to another control block, so that a control block only ever points to one same object. In other words, there is no replacement of one object with another in the control block.

Comment: "_special lock-free (code language for busy spin) function_" lock-free doesn't mean busy spin, it means no thread can put the object in state where another threads cannot take over and perform; it also means a low priority thread can in theory stall a high priority thread forever

Answer (score 12):

### Short answer

I suspect most implementations achieve this by having a shared control block that both `weakPtr` and `sharedPtr` refer to.  When `sharedPtr` is reset, it decrements a `use_count` in the control block that the `weakPtr` can use to test if the pointer is valid.

### Long answer

But I think that could vary depending on the implementation.  Here's a blow-by-blow of what the C++11 standard says should happen:

```
shared_ptr<MySharedStruct> sharedPtr(new MySharedStruct());
```

Per *20.7.2.2.1*, `sharedPtr` is constructed with ownership of the given data.

```
weak_ptr<MySharedStruct> weakPtr;
weakPtr = sharedPtr;
```

Per *20.7.2.3.1*, `weakPtr` is constructed and then assigned a value of `sharedPtr`. After the assignment, `weakPtr` and `sharedPtr` now share ownership of the given data.

```
sharedPtr.reset(new MySharedStruct());
```

Per *20.7.2.2.4*, `reset(Y*)` is equivalent to `shared_ptr(Y*).swap(*this)`.  In other words, `sharedPtr` swaps its contents with a temporary `shared_ptr` that owns the new data.

After the swap, `sharedPtr` will own the new data, and the temporary will share ownership of the old data with `weakPtr`.

Per *20.7.2.2.2*, the temporary is then destructed:

- Since the temporary owns the old data and does not share that ownership with another `shared_ptr` instance, it deletes the old data.
- All instances that share ownership with the temporary `shared_ptr` will report a `use_count()` that is one less than its previous value.

That means that `weakPtr.use_count() == 0`.

```
if (shared_ptr<MySharedStruct> sp = weakPtr.lock()) { 
  cout << "Value of i = " << sp->i << endl;
} else {
  cout << "Resource has expired"; 
}
```

Per *20.7.2.3.5*, calling `lock` is equivalent to

```
expired() ? shared_ptr<T>() : shared_ptr<T>(*this)
```

...and `expired()` is equivalent to

```
use_count() == 0
```

...which means `lock` will return an empty `shared_ptr`.