# Why shared_ptr's reference counting object needs to keep track of the number of weak_ptrs pointing to the object too?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

Hi I am reading through [this document](http://umich.edu/~eecs381/handouts/C++11_smart_ptrs.pdf) and some other documents about C++'s `shared_ptr` and they all seem to suggest that apart from the number of `shared_ptr` pointing to the allocated object, the reference count object has to keep track of how many `weak_ptr` pointer pointing to the object as well. My question is why? From my understanding, `weak_ptr` is non-owning so if the count of `shared_ptr` pointing to the object reaches zero the object can be deleted. That is why sometimes we need to use [expired](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/expired) to check the availability of an object pointed by a `weak_ptr`. Could you explain the reason for needing to keep track of the number of `weak_ptr`s?

Why do we need weak count here?
[image]

Comment: I believe it's because otherwise, the `weak_ptr` wouldn't be able to know if it was expired. You have the keep the block of memory alive so that the `weak_ptr`s know that the pointer has expired, but you also want to delete the memory after all the `weak_ptr`s are gone

Comment: @Justin I was like "Can't you just test wp1's pointer to the manager object is null" and then I realised "Ah, of course you cannot do that otherwise you solved the problem of deleting a ptr twice will seg fault your program issue."

Comment: Basically, the only other solution would be to keep a list of all `weak_ptr`s stored. Then, when the shared count gets to 0, you inform every `weak_ptr` that the memory was destroyed. This would be less efficient, especially in terms of memory used.

Comment: As a sidenote, your graphic is misleading because the pointer to the managed object is stored inside each `shared_ptr`/`weak_ptr`. There may be another pointer inside the deleter (inside the control block aka manager object). This allows different pointer instances to have the same ownership relation but *different pointees*.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14043328/412080

Comment: @Justin "_you inform every weak_ptr that the memory was destroyed_" creating the possibility of having some expired and other non expired weak ref to the same object, during a short time which could be extended indefinitely if some weak ref is turned into a strong ref!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`std::weak_ptr` refers to the control block to know if the object still exists and if so, to provide a `std::shared_ptr` to it when needed. For that reason, the control block must exist as long as either a `std::weak_ptr` or a `std::shared_ptr` exists. You need to track the number of instances of `std::weak_ptr` to know when the last one is destroyed, just like for `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Right, if it weren't so, the control block would need to contain information about all `weak_ptr` instances so that they can be nulled out (in a thread-safe manner, no less) on expiry. It's much easier to let the `weak_ptr` perform polling on `lock()` instead.

Answer (score 6):

The `shared_ptr` reference count is the count of owners of the object. The `weak_ptr` reference count is the count of owners of the reference count control block.

Comment: So, you are claiming a new shared pointer adds 1 to both values?

Comment: @Yakk: Yes, but good implementations make the population of shared_ptrs behave as one weak_ptr.

Comment: @Yakk Increment two integers is problematic WRT atomicity.

Comment: @curious it doesn't need atomicity.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the answer by François Andrieux:

There is a side effect of this that is very important to understand.

If you use an implementation of std::make_shared that uses the WKWYL optimization (We Know Where You Live) of allocating the control block and the actual object together as one contiguous allocation, the memory WILL NOT BE FREED until after all weak_ptr objects have also gone out of scope.

(my account is seldom used, so I cannot add comments, due to not having enough reputation points, thus adding as an answer rather than a comment)