# cleaning non-owning pointers after object destruction

Tags: c++

i usually find this snippet creeping into my code where two objects that don't own each other need to have a pointer to one another, and this pointer should be "cleaned" once one of them is destroyed as follows.

```
struct bar;
struct foo;

struct foo
{
    bar* bar_item = nullptr;
    ~foo();
};

struct bar
{
    foo* foo_item = nullptr;
    ~bar()
    {
        if (foo_item)
        {
            foo_item->bar_item = nullptr;
        }
    }
};

foo::~foo()
{
    if (bar_item)
    {
        bar_item->foo_item = nullptr;
    }
}

int main()
{
    foo obj1;
    bar obj2;
    obj1.bar_item = &obj2;
    obj2.foo_item = &obj1;
}
```

the problem here is that i have to either

1. delete the copy constructor/assignment and implement the move constructor/assignment (a lot of boiler-plate, expect at least 5 members per class)
2. convert all objects into shared_ptr and objects will have weak_ptr to one another. (maybe not always feasible as i may not own the objects lifetime, also forces me to use the heap)

is there some way to avoid this ? simplify it ? have an RAII wrapper for a specific member to avoid implementing the copy/move operations ?

a simple example i once ran into is a graphics system where i need a line to connect two spheres, the line should have pointers to both spheres and the spheres should have a pointer to the line, all of them are owned by the "scene", but asking the "scene" about them requires a long lookup, the pointers avoid this lookup.

Comment: There are some classical approaches to solve cyclic problem and you listed some of them (others include mediator, garbage collector, etc.). There is no silver bullet and approach choice should be made based on current situation. So this could be simplified only if real conditions are known. So, give more information on why do you have such situation and what is the code around. For this simple example I would set pointer to nullptr just from `main`, but, again, this is "the answer is as good as your code snippet for it".

Comment: Are all those just "observer" pointers? You can have a container that will store all the pointers to the observed objects, then you won’t have problems with copy construction  at the expense of even more boilerplate and storage. It really depends on what you’re trying to achieve.

Comment: @DamirTenishev i added an example of something i once ran into, but i am generically seeing if someone has a solution for this creeping snippet.

Comment: Use `std::weak_ptr` with `std::shared_ptr`, and have those templates handle this for you.

Comment: Well, without the context, I would recommend [How to break shared_ptr cyclic reference using weak_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27085782/how-to-break-shared-ptr-cyclic-reference-using-weak-ptr) to see the easy way and then [What is the cyclic dependency issue with shared_ptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22185896/what-is-the-cyclic-dependency-issue-with-shared-ptr) to see how far it goes and [How does a weak_ptr know ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043245/how-does-a-weak-ptr-know-that-the-shared-resources-has-expired) finally.

Comment: There is no silver bullet here and if you go with `std::weak_ptr` with `std::shared_ptr` which is mostly recommended and used approach here, you will face many interesting things while locking and going to multi-threading, so it all totally depends on where you want to put this code.

Comment: First of all you need to understand what means to copy the object, in fact once you copy one, for example bar2, both bar and bar2 will point to foo, but foo will still point only to bar. Using shared_ptr is quite questionable for members, as they say here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=juAZDfsaMvY 
In your example with spheres and line, if the objects are owned by scene, wouldn't scene be responsible to manage the pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> delete the copy constructor/assignment and implement the move constructor/assignment (a lot of boiler-plate, expect at least 5 members per class)

That's usually an indicator that one can do better. We shouldn't define special member functions for the sake of data members. Those data members should define special member functions.

For example, one can define a pointer type which automatically resets a linked pointer.

```
template <typename T, auto GetLink>
class link_ptr {
public:
    link_ptr& operator=(T* rhs) {
        if (rhs != t) {
            resetLink();
            t = rhs;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    ~link_ptr() {
        resetLink();
    }

    void reset() {
        t = nullptr;
    }

    void resetLink() {
        if (t) {
            GetLink(*t).reset();
        }
    }

private:
    T* t = nullptr;
};
```

And then use it:

```
struct bar;
struct foo
{
    link_ptr<bar, get_foo_link> bar_link;
};
    
struct bar
{
    link_ptr<foo, get_bar_link> foo_link;
};
```

The `link_ptr` code is generic and only written once. The only true boilerplate is the getters, which is probably acceptable:

```
constexpr auto get_foo_link = [](auto& o) -> auto& { return o.foo_link; };
constexpr auto get_bar_link = [](auto& o) -> auto& { return o.bar_link; };
```

Here's an example: https://godbolt.org/z/5feKdKcMr.

As you've mentioned and as the comments have mentioned, there are alternative designs (e.g. using `weak_ptr` or indexing into an arena among others), but this option shows the observer pointer might not need as much boilerplate as one might think.